# How to ensure the alarm is invoke even I haven't open the app in android?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

Currently I work on a reminder android app, since it remind people to take the pill , so it is really important for the system not missing the alarm.

I found some tutorial and create the code like this:

```
setTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2014,5,4,15,4); // Month start at 0 , meaning January is 0
            long dateTime = date.getTimeInMillis();
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        }
    });
```

Mainfest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<receiver android:name=".Listener.AlarmReceiver" />
```

Receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The problem is I wonder will the alarm invoke even I haven't open the app. The only case missing the alarm is when the user turn off the device? Thanks

Comment: look this http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a background service through your app which takes care of setting up alarms and firing them even when your app is not opened or in the foreground. Here's a tutorial on services ----> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html